# What are the possibitlities to effectively parse YAML file in Scala? How to use it in scala?

Tags: scala, parsing, dynamic, yaml, snakeyaml

I want to make a configuration file for my certain variables, so that I don't have to change in code each time.
I want to do it by making a YAML file. I am working with scala.
What are the effective ways to use these variables by reading from yaml into my application.

So far, I have looked in snakeyaml library but it contains java functions and parses yaml in a string by which I can't go into nested key value pair of yaml file without splitting the string.
How can I use these by staying in scala and what are the better ways to parse as i would need to get the nested values often. How can I use it in my application?

eg
if this is my yaml file

```
---
accountName: Ymail Account
username: johndoe
password: secret
mailbox: INBOX
imapServerUrl: imap.mail.yahoo.com
protocol: imaps
minutesBetweenChecks: 1
usersOfInterest: [barney, betty, wilma]
...
```

I want to get each index of userOfInterst individually as needed.

so far I have done like this

```
  @BeanProperty var accountName = ""
  @BeanProperty var username = ""
  @BeanProperty var password = ""
  @BeanProperty var mailbox = ""
  @BeanProperty var imapServerUrl = ""
  @BeanProperty var protocol = ""
  @BeanProperty var minutesBetweenChecks = 0
  @BeanProperty var usersOfInterest = new java.util.ArrayList[String]
  override def toString: String = s"acct: $accountName, user: $username, url: $imapServerUrl, uot: $usersOfInterest," +
    s"mbc: $minutesBetweenChecks"
```

but it just prints all as string which isnt helpful. What are the other options and how to get it dynamically?

Comment: Not really answering your question but something more "idiomatic" in Scala is using https://github.com/lightbend/config (and the HOCON syntax)

Comment: SnakeYAML generally does *not* parse YAML into a string, that won't be „parsing“. I am not quite sure whether a Scala class is properly understood by SnakeYAML, but you can always define your file's layout as simple POJO, load the YAML via SnakeYAML into that, and then use it in Scala.

Comment: Jackson has support for Yaml (https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-yaml) and Jackson has a Scala Module so you might be able to create an ObjectMapper that deserializes Yaml to a Scala case class using Jackson.

Comment: I had a go using circe-yaml: have a look: https://gist.github.com/mfirry/82ebaa605d493eb80dd7600a872faeda